# Resolve merge conflict by default with "theirs" when doing a git rebase -i

Tags: git, rebase, squash

we have a big repo that has more than 35k commits and I want to basically go back and squash historical commits that have been done 2 years ago. In order to do this I did a 'git rebase -i' and changed a lot of commits from pick to squash. Now the rebase stops and ask me to resolve merge conflicts, which basically I resolve with 'checkout --theirs'. As far as I can see is asking to resolve merge conflict every 2 or 3 commits, which in 35k is driving me crazy.
Is there a way I can make the rebase do that automatically instead of asking me to do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is nothing that does exactly what you are doing. But I will say: *don't do what you are doing*, it does not work well in practice. 35k commits is not that big, either: the Git repo for Git has 52193 (as of this comment), and the Linux kernel has over 700k.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to reduce it's size as it's around 400Mb when we don't have any file bigger than 5Mb, so I suspect is because of it's history. But yes, I figured doing this was going to be a crazy task

Comment: That's sizeable, but not crazy-huge: the Git repo for Git is 119M, whlie the Git repo for Linux is ~2.4 GB, for instance, and the one for FreeBSD is ~3.3 GB. Note that you can use shallow clones (`git clone --depth <number>`) to reduce download time and space (and eventually deepen or "unshallow" such a clone if necessary).

Comment: Thanks @torek I'll take a look at shallow clones